# NoClassDefFoundError and Netty

Tags: java, memcached

First to say I'm n00b in Java. I can understand most concepts but in my situation I want somebody to help me. I'm using JBoss Netty to handle simple http request and using MemCachedClient check existence of client ip in memcached.

```
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import static org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders.*;
import static org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders.Names.*;
import static org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus.*;
import static org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.*;
import com.danga.MemCached.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.Cookie;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.CookieDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.CookieEncoder;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunk;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkTrailer;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.QueryStringDecoder;
import org.jboss.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

/**
* @author <a href="http://www.jboss.org/netty/">The Netty Project</a>
* @author Andy Taylor (andy.taylor@jboss.org)
* @author <a href="http://gleamynode.net/">Trustin Lee</a>
*
* @version $Rev: 2368 $, $Date: 2010-10-18 17:19:03 +0900 (Mon, 18 Oct 2010) $
*/
@SuppressWarnings({"ALL"})
public class HttpRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    private HttpRequest request;
    private boolean readingChunks;
    /** Buffer that stores the response content */
    private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    protected MemCachedClient mcc = new MemCachedClient();
    private static SockIOPool poolInstance = null;

    static {

// server list and weights
        String[] servers =
                {
                        "lcalhost:11211"
                };

//Integer[] weights = { 3, 3, 2 };
        Integer[] weights = {1};

// grab an instance of our connection pool
        SockIOPool pool = SockIOPool.getInstance();

// set the servers and the weights
        pool.setServers(servers);
        pool.setWeights(weights);

// set some basic pool settings
// 5 initial, 5 min, and 250 max conns
// and set the max idle time for a conn
// to 6 hours
        pool.setInitConn(5);
        pool.setMinConn(5);
        pool.setMaxConn(250);
        pool.setMaxIdle(21600000); //1000 * 60 * 60 * 6

// set the sleep for the maint thread
// it will wake up every x seconds and
// maintain the pool size
        pool.setMaintSleep(30);

// set some TCP settings
// disable nagle
// set the read timeout to 3 secs
// and don't set a connect timeout
        pool.setNagle(false);
        pool.setSocketTO(3000);
        pool.setSocketConnectTO(0);

// initialize the connection pool
        pool.initialize();


// lets set some compression on for the client
// compress anything larger than 64k
        //mcc.setCompressEnable(true);
        //mcc.setCompressThreshold(64 * 1024);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        if(mcc.get(request.getHeader("X-Real-Ip")) != null)
        {
            HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
            response.setHeader("X-Accel-Redirect", request.getUri());
            ctx.getChannel().write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
        else {
            sendError(ctx, NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }

    private void writeResponse(MessageEvent e) {
        // Decide whether to close the connection or not.
        boolean keepAlive = isKeepAlive(request);

        // Build the response object.
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);
        response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(buf.toString(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
        response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        if (keepAlive) {
            // Add 'Content-Length' header only for a keep-alive connection.
            response.setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.getContent().readableBytes());
        }

        // Encode the cookie.
        String cookieString = request.getHeader(COOKIE);
        if (cookieString != null) {
            CookieDecoder cookieDecoder = new CookieDecoder();
            Set<Cookie> cookies = cookieDecoder.decode(cookieString);
            if(!cookies.isEmpty()) {
                // Reset the cookies if necessary.
                CookieEncoder cookieEncoder = new CookieEncoder(true);
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    cookieEncoder.addCookie(cookie);
                }
                response.addHeader(SET_COOKIE, cookieEncoder.encode());
            }
        }

        // Write the response.
        ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response);

        // Close the non-keep-alive connection after the write operation is done.
        if (!keepAlive) {
            future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        e.getChannel().close();
    }


    private void sendError(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpResponseStatus status) {
         HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, status);
         response.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
         response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(
                 "Failure: " + status.toString() + "\r\n",
                 CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

         // Close the connection as soon as the error message is sent.
         ctx.getChannel().write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

}
```

When I try to send request like http://127.0.0.1:8090/1/2/3
I'm getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/danga/MemCached/MemCachedClient
        at httpClientValidator.server.HttpRequestHandler.<clinit>(HttpRequestHandler.java:66)
```

I believe it's not related to classpath. May be it's related to context in which mcc doesn't exist.
Any help appreciated

EDIT:
Original code http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html
I've modified some parts to fit my needs.

Comment: If I replace static declaration with instance declaration java complains about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/danga/MemCached/SockIOPool. So I'm sure it's related to context. I don't know how to pass protected static MemCachedClient into instance of HttpRequestHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think this is not classpath related? That's the kind of error you get when the jar you need is not available. How do you start your app?

EDIT

Sorry - i loaded and tried the java_memcached-release_2.5.2 bundle in eclipse and found no issue so far. Debugging the class loading revealed nothing unusual. I can't help besides some more hints to double check:

- make sure your download is correct. download and unpack again. (are the com.schooner.* classes available?)
- make sure you use > java 1.5
- make sure your classpath is correct and complete. The example you have shown does not include netty. Where is it.
- I'm not familiar with interactions stemming from adding a classpath to the manifest. Maybe revert to plain style, add all jars needed (memcached, netty, yours) to the classpath and reference the main class to start, not a startable jar file

Comment: I added module dependency in IDEA as usual with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S -> Modules -> Dependencies.
This works as expected for Netty but doesn't for MemcacheClient. I even tried to copy java_memcached-release_2.5.2.jar into the same folder as my HTTPClientValidator.jar and run: "java -ea -Xmx256m -classpath .;.\java_memcached-release_2.5.2.jar -jar HTTPClientValidator.jar". Nothing helps

Comment: Look at the comment to my question. Replacing protected static MemCachedClient mcc = new MemCachedClient(); with protected MemCachedClient mcc = new MemCachedClient(); resolves initial exception but similar exception appeared about SockIOPool

Comment: I've seen this. As i said, the recursive loading caused by MemCachedCLient is fine when monitored in the debugger. Give the checklist a try. For more - i'm at a loss...

Comment: JDK ver 1.6.0_23, jar SHA1 checksum 9f0072e0dbcfe29a4c0e2ca7bbdb3ba6a8fdc98c, CLASSPATH as in commandline includes .
I've uploaded my project source along with compiled JAR which includes netty and memcacheclient JARs to http://www.mediafire.com/?z2sn4zdidox8plx

Comment: You were right. Execution without JAR solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Will continue to improve my Java knowledge :)